# Contenteditable elements change ID after modifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have some problems with a contenteditable div annoying behaviour. I have a few elements inside, let's say the code looks like that:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p id="element-id-1">element-id-1</p>
    <p id="element-id-2">element-id-2</p>
</div>
```

All works as intended except for one thing - when I triple click the first paragraph to select and remove it (with delete or backspace) the second paragraph content 'jumps' into its place, but retains the first paragraph ID. Is there a way to prevent this, so after I triple click the first paragraph and remove it, the second paragraph remains with the same ID (#element-id-2)? JSFiddle with described functionality here: https://jsfiddle.net/t8e28bmx/ Thanks!

Comment: it's remove all content with tag when you click on delete and triple click even select internally whole html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<div contenteditable="plaintext-only">
  <p id="element-id-1">element-id-1</p>
  <p id="element-id-2">element-id-2</p>
</div>
```

Reference: https://w3c.github.io/editing/contentEditable.html#h-contenteditable

Comment: Thanks, but it still retains the first paragraph ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<p contenteditable="true" id="element-id-1">element-id-1</p>
<p contenteditable="true" id="element-id-2">element-id-2</p>
</div>
```